# Format to number with comma JSF

Tags: jsf

How I can format a value in JSF

```
<h:outputText  value="#{MyVM.number}">
<f:convertNumber pattern="#0,000.000" />
</h:outputText>
```

I need format a number like: 12345.67 to 12,345.67
Is possible with pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use:

```
 <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true"
                 maxFractionDigits="2"  />
```