# Unable to accept input numbers after I use p inputMask, add a comma for numbers more than 999

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, input-mask

For the input text field below, 
User can enter the values between one and 99,999.
Enter only numbers.

```
<p:message for="usage" display="text"><p:autoUpdate/></p:message>
<p:inputText id="usage" maxlength="10" required="true"
    requiredMessage="You must provide an input" value="#{powerMB.usage}">  
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1" maximum="99999" for="usage" />   
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9]/i"  />         
</p:inputText>
```

Current Input values accept - examples

```
1 
34                      
99
3534
53535
```

I have tried to **mask a specific input values** as per

[How to restrict Primefaces inputMask to numbers only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437146/how-to-restrict-primefaces-inputmask-to-numbers-only?rq=1)

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml

Tried to **add a comma for numbers** more than 999

I receive the following error for the code below

```
usage: Validation Error: Value is not of the correct type
```

---

```
<p:message for="usage" display="text"><p:autoUpdate/></p:message>
<p:inputMask id="usage" maxlength="5" required="true"
    requiredMessage="You must provide an input" mask="99,999" value="#{powerMB.usage}">  
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1" maximum="99999" for="usage" />   
</p:inputMask>
```

Input Given as

```
1       fail validation error
34      fail                
99      fail
3534    fail
53535   fail


00,001      fail validation error
00,034      fail                
00,099      fail
03,534  fail
053,535 fail
```

unable to accept input values after I use inputMask

Can provide a full working code of the existing functionality if needed.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313080/format-to-number-with-comma-jsf) would help you?

Answer (score 5):

This is not the answer to your requirement but it is an explanation on why you see the behaviour you see.

All your failures are easily explained...

The comma is **required** so all these rightfully fail

```
1       fail validation error
34      fail                
99      fail
3534    fail
53535   fail
```

Secondly your maxLength is 5 so all these rightfully fail since the length is 6

```
00,001      fail validation error
00,034      fail                
00,099      fail
03,534      fail
```

And this fails for a combination of reasons

```
053,535     fail
```

SNAFU

To make the comma optional look for better matching patterns. It is for me beyond the effort I want to put in this.